# Get heights of child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to access the heights of child components in React but can't find any clear guidance on how best to do it. My Component looks like this:

```
/* index.js */
import Blocks from './Blocks'

ReactDOM.render(<Blocks />, document.body)

/* Blocks.jsx */
import Block from './Block'

class Blocks extends Component {
  render () {
    const eles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    return (
      <div>
        {eles.map(e => <Block key={e}>{e}</Block>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to know the size and position of each of those `Block`s as I want to position them myself later.

As far as I can see, this approach doesn't allow me to use `this.props.children` to access the elements which is annoying as rendering the blocks in this way is much better for me (there's going to be logic around which type of `Block` to render later). To get around this I've tried moving the rendering of the `Block`s into the index file like this:

```
/* index.js */
import Blocks from './Blocks'
import Block from './Block'

const eles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Blocks>
    {eles.map(e => <Block key={e}>{e}</Block>)}
  </Blocks>
)

/* Blocks.jsx */
class Blocks extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What this allows me to do is use `refs` inside the individual `Block` components to return the result of their `getBoundingClientRect` function which I should be able to access through the parent but I'm now reading that using `refs` is discouraged and not how React is supposed to be used.

I need to be able to pin certain `Block`s to the top of the screen as they are scrolled past and can't think of any other way of doing it than knowing their sizes and positions in a parent component and using that to manage them. Is there any way of doing this? Ideally I would like to move that loop back inside of the `Blocks` component otherwise I'm going to have some of it's logic in an unrelated component which doesn't seem right.

I've also looked into using `react-sticky` but as the app I'm building is already inside a fixed position element (which is unavoidable) I don't think it'll help me.

Comment: What if each generic block will be responsible for its own size calculations, sending the results back into parent via given endpoint?

Comment: `eles.map(e => <Block ref={ref => this.blocks[e] = this.blocks[e] || ref} key={e}>{e}</Block>)` and you will have all required refs in componentDidMount()

Comment: I didn't think of creating the refs in the `Blocks` component, that's much simpler than anything I was trying to do. Am I right in thinking there's no way to do this without refs? I know we've had trouble with testing before (and everything I read seems to try and dissuade me from using them). Submit this as an answer and I'll accept - cheers @elmeister

Answer (score 8):

try to use callback function in Block Component to send the ref to the Parent Component

Block.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Block extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getRef(this.block, this.props.i);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={n => this.block = n}>
        <p>{this.props.children}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Block;
```

save the refs into variable or state in `index.js`,
and then in `componentDidMount` method,  you can get the Block component height or other property.
index.js

```
const eles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.blocks = [];
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.blocks);
    this.blocks.forEach((block, i) => {
      console.log(i, block.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    })
  }

  getRef = (ref, i) => {
    this.blocks[i] = ref;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {eles.map((e, i) => (
          <Block key={e} i={i} getRef={this.getRef}>{e}</Block>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

the result in console
[image]

Comment: wouldn't this thrash the layout every time the component is re rendered?